# Convert a flow type React component to JSX - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, flowtype

I am in need of an accessible tooltip component in React and came across [React Tooltip](https://github.com/ryami333/react-accessible-tooltip). Its written in flow but I use jsx in my build. I want to convert the syntax to jsx but hitting a roadblock in the render method. Please advice on what I need to change.

Flow Tooltip: https://pastebin.com/EfQQBKZ0

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import type { ElementProps, ComponentType } from 'react';

export type LabelProps = {
    labelAttributes: {
        tabIndex: '0',
        'aria-describedby': string,
        onFocus: () => void,
    },
    isHidden: boolean,
};

export type OverlayProps = {
    overlayAttributes: {
        role: 'tooltip',
        tabIndex: '-1',
        id: string,
        'aria-hidden': string,
    },
    isHidden: boolean,
};

export type TooltipState = {
    isFocused: boolean,
    isHovered: boolean,
};

export type TooltipProps = ElementProps<'div'> & {
    label: ComponentType<LabelProps>,
    overlay: ComponentType<OverlayProps>,
};

let counter = 0;

class Tooltip extends Component<TooltipProps, TooltipState> {
    constructor(props: TooltipProps) {
        super(props);
        this.identifier = `react-accessible-tooltip-${counter}`;
        counter += 1;
    }

    state = {
        isFocused: false,
        isHovered: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.handleTouch);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.handleTouch);
    }

    onFocus = () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: true });
    };

    onBlur = ({
        relatedTarget,
        currentTarget,
    }: SyntheticFocusEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        // relatedTarget is better for React testability etc, but activeElement works as an IE11 fallback:
        const newTarget = relatedTarget || document.activeElement;

        // The idea of this logic is that we should only close the tooltip if focus has shifted from the tooltip AND all of its descendents.
        if (!(newTarget && newTarget instanceof HTMLElement)) {
            this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        } else if (!currentTarget.contains(newTarget)) {
            this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        }
    };

    onMouseEnter = () => {
        this.setState({ isHovered: true });
    };

    onMouseLeave = () => {
        this.setState({ isHovered: false });
    };

    // This handles the support for touch devices that do not trigger blur on 'touch-away'.
    handleTouch = ({ target }: Event) => {
        const { activeElement } = document;

        if (
            activeElement instanceof Element &&
            target instanceof Element &&
            this.container instanceof Element &&
            !this.container.contains(target) && // touch target not a tooltip descendent
            this.state.isFocused // prevent redundant state change
        ) {
            this.setState({ isFocused: false });
            activeElement.blur();
        } else if (
            activeElement instanceof Element &&
            target instanceof Element &&
            this.container instanceof Element &&
            this.container.contains(target) && // touch target is on tooltip descendant
            !this.state.isFocused // prevent redundant state change
        ) {
            this.setState({ isFocused: true });
        }
    };

    handleKeyDown = ({ key, keyCode, which }: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (key === 'Escape' || keyCode === 27 || which === 27) {
            this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        }
    };

    container: ?HTMLDivElement;
    identifier: string;

    render() {
        const { label: Label, overlay: Overlay, ...rest } = this.props;

        const { isFocused, isHovered } = this.state;
        const isHidden = !(isFocused || isHovered);

        const labelProps: LabelProps = {
            labelAttributes: {
                tabIndex: '0',
                'aria-describedby': this.identifier,
                onFocus: this.onFocus,
            },
            isHidden,
        };

        const overlayProps: OverlayProps = {
            overlayAttributes: {
                role: 'tooltip',
                tabIndex: '-1',
                id: this.identifier,
                'aria-hidden': isHidden.toString(),
            },
            isHidden,
        };

        return (
            <div
                {...rest}
                onBlur={this.onBlur}
                ref={ref => {
                    this.container = ref;
                }}
                onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
            >
                <Label {...labelProps} />
                <Overlay {...overlayProps} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Tooltip;
```

JSX Tooltip: https://pastebin.com/QhQqRw24

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import InfoIcon from '../../InfoIcon/InfoIcon';

let counter = 0;

class TooltipContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFocused: false,
      isHovered: false,
    };
    this.identifier = `react-accessible-tooltip-${counter}`;
    counter += 1;
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.handleTouch = this.handleTouch.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.container = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.handleTouch);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.handleTouch);
  }

  onFocus() {
    this.setState({ isFocused: true });
  };

  onBlur({
    relatedTarget,
    currentTarget,
  }){
    // relatedTarget is better for React testability etc, but activeElement works as an IE11 fallback:
    const newTarget = relatedTarget || document.activeElement;

    // The idea of this logic is that we should only close the tooltip if focus has shifted from the tooltip AND all of its descendents.
    if (!(newTarget)) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: false });
    } else if (!currentTarget.contains(newTarget)) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: false });
    }
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    this.setState({ isHovered: true });
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({ isHovered: false });
  }

  // This handles the support for touch devices that do not trigger blur on 'touch-away'.
  handleTouch({ target }) {
    const { activeElement } = document;

    if (
      activeElement instanceof Element &&
      target instanceof Element &&
      this.container instanceof Element &&
      !this.container.contains(target) && // touch target not a tooltip descendent
      this.state.isFocused // prevent redundant state change
    ) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: false });
      activeElement.blur();
    } else if (
      activeElement instanceof Element &&
      target instanceof Element &&
      this.container instanceof Element &&
      this.container.contains(target) && // touch target is on tooltip descendant
      !this.state.isFocused // prevent redundant state change
    ) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: true });
    }
  }

  handleKeyDown({ key, keyCode, which }) {
    if (key === 'Escape' || keyCode === 27 || which === 27) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: false });
    }
  }


  render() {
    console.log('props', this.props)
    const { label: Label, overlay: Overlay, ...rest } = this.props;

    const { isFocused, isHovered } = this.state;
    const isHidden = !(isFocused || isHovered);

    const labelProps = {
      labelAttributes: {
        tabIndex: '0',
        'aria-describedby': this.identifier,
        onFocus: this.onFocus,
      },
      isHidden,
    };

    const overlayProps = {
      overlayAttributes: {
        role: 'tooltip',
        tabIndex: '-1',
        id: this.identifier,
        'aria-hidden': isHidden.toString(),
      },
      isHidden,
    };

    return (
      <div
        {...rest}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        ref={ref => {
          this.container = ref;
        }}
        onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
      >
        <a><InfoIcon icon={faInfoCircle} {...labelProps} /></a>
        <Overlay {...overlayProps} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TooltipContainer;
```

Comment: "Its written in flow but I use jsx in my build" -- Flow and JSX are not mutually exclusive. Both Flow and JSX get "translated" into vanilla JavaScript (Flow gets removed, JSX gets converted into React.createElement calls, normally). Both can coexist and, therefore, should not be causing issues interacting together. Could you clarify the issue you're having?

Answer (score 1):

I just can not get, why you don't want to just install that package and use it following API description.

Related to your question, Flow it's just a type checker, if you want to get rid of it, just remove flow-related things from the code.

I see that you did some not related to flow changes, for example, refs. In your example with the flow, there is a callback refs, but in your example without, you're trying to use new refs API, but still using it as a callback refs. That's from the first look, mb there is more other things...

Plus

> roadblock in the render

doesn't sound informative, what issue you have faced.